# Replacing a dll with the static library

Tags: c++, dll, static, linker

**Staring point:**
I have some C++ code that links to a third party static library which links to ws2_32.lib.

**Goal:**
I am investigating ways to port this C++ code to an embedded platform that is essentially a Win32 platform, except it does not allow any dlls and has a proprietary UDP protocol implementation.

**Strategy:**
I would like to write a static library that mimics winsock API (or at least a subset of this API that I care about).  These relevant winsock functions will serve as wrappers to the proprietary UDP function calls supported by the embedded platform.

**Assumption:**
I can link this static library to the final executable instead of the ws2_32.lib.

**Questions:**

1. Is my assumption correct/reasonable?
2. How do I set up the linking mechanically?

**What I have done:**
I have attempted to do so on just one function, and cannot seem to link.  This is what I have defined in my static library:

```
unsigned short __stdcall htons(unsigned short hostshort) {
    return hostshort;
}
```

When I link, I get the following error:

```
: error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__htons@4
```

This `__imp__` prefix in the link message is something I do not quite understand.  Does the name of the function defined in the dll change in some special way, and can I fake this in a static library to somehow force the linker to link with my version of the function instead of the one in ws2_32.lib?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to go down the path of replacing Winsock with a proprietary network stack.

However, if all you need to do is to mock simple routines like `htons`, you can get away with that.

You need to mark your routines as `extern "C"`, and likely need to mark them as being exported.

```
extern "C" 
{
__declspec(dllexport) 
unsigned short __stdcall htons(unsigned short a) { return a; }
}
```

If you don't mark them as C-compatible externs, the linker does some [name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B_Name_Mangling).

Comment: As a matter of fact, I am quite embarrassed that I did not think about `extern "C"`.  Did the trick perfectly in combination with the post by Ben above.  All I had to do is to rename my file from `FakeWS2_32.cpp` to `FakeWS2_32.c` and define `unsigned short __stdcall _imp__htons(unsigned short a) { return a; }`.  Link was successful.

These mechanics aside, what would you recommend as an alternative to reimplementing some 20 winsock functions in my situation?

Comment: There is no alternative.  I suspect Zach is recommending against replacing the network stack included with Windows... since your platform doesn't even have a Windows network stack, it doesn't apply (you can't replace what isn't there).

Comment: Good point. From my chair, I see no alternative.  I am just hoping to be able to find a small enough subset of the winsock API calls that I will need to re-implement and hopefully I can do it with the proprietary API given.  Thanks to everyone for your help.  It really works quite well.

Answer (score 0):

The `__imp__` prefix indicates that it is a trampoline (tail call) to a DLL function.  This makes dynamic linking efficient, because there's only one place where the actual address of the library function needs to be changed during library load and fix-up.  The compiler looks for it because the header file used `__declspec(dllimport)` on the function declaration.

You can either strip out (possibly via macro) the `dllimport` from `winsock2.h` or define your implementation with the `_imp__` prefix.

Comment: Trying the `_imp__` prefix in my function definition was the first thing that came to my mind.  Did not help.  If the third party library was compiled with `__declspec(dllimport)` in the winsock header file, changing it now is not going to do anything for me either. The third party library is where the link errors originate, and I cannot recompile it as I have no source code.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: Thanks, Ben.  See below.  It was a combination of your suggestion and the c-style linkage that did the trick.